# Mongoose find all then mark documents that match User ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Whats the best way to find all records, says `Post` and then mark only the posts that belong to the logged-in User with some flag (assuming a post can belong to many users). Ideally, I want this to happen on the server so if I have 100 total posts with `Post.find({})` I could get Mongoose documents or JSON objects that look like the following:

```
[{title: "some Post", userPost: true}, {title: "another post}, {title: "third post", userPost: true}, {title: "Last post"}]
```

In this result, I could then decorate user posts in a specific way. However, I want to query for all posts, but only user posts, and because this is not going through a templating engine I need the flag to exist in the JSON response to indicate the relationship to the current user.

Currently, I have a function that looks like the following:

```
let currentUser;
Post.find().exec( ( error, posts ) => {
    posts.map( ( p ) => {
            let userPosted = currentUser.posts.some((userPost) => {
                return userPost.equals(p._id)
            });
            return Object.assign(p.toObject(), {userPost: userPosted});
    } );
} );
```

Any suggestions on improvements? Should this filter function go on the Post model? Is there a more efficient way to do this in the initial query? I know of `lean()` in Mongoose that will return JSON instead of Mongoose documents so I don't need to make that conversion. I'm open to thoughts.

Comment: Something like `Post.aggregate({$project:{"title":1, userPost:{$eq:['$_id', currentUser.ID]}}}).exec( ( error, posts ) => {} );`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram. It looks like this is asking for an aggregation of posts returning the title and `userPost` set to whether the post's ID equals the user's ID. Is that right?

Comment: np. yes that is correct.

Comment: In my case the Post schema has an `_id`, and `title`. User schema has an array of post objectIDs in `currentUser.courses`. So I need to see if, in the aggregation, the post's ID matches any of the user's posts' IDs. So i don't think it will help to see if the post's ID matches the user's ID as they will never be the same.

Comment: I see. Try `Post.aggregate({$project:{"title":1, userPost:{$in:['$_id', currentUser.posts]}}}).exec( ( error, posts ) => {} )` in 3.4 mongo server version.

Comment: Thanks. This looks clean but I'm not getting any results. I'm wondering if there is an issue in comparing the post's ID `$_id` with the way course IDs are represented in `user.courses`. Maybe there is an issue here like comparing ID as a string with MongoDB ObjectID? I feel this answer is close but I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: Np. Use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(stringid)` to convert courses string id into objectid before sending them to aggregation.

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, I'll play around with this solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing something along these lines:

```
    //first you need something associating the current user
    const currentUser = ?;
    const alteredPosts = [];
    //get all posts from Mongo
    Post.find({})
    .exec(error, posts => {
         if(error) console.error(error);
         //search through all posts and find those by the current user
         alteredPosts = posts.map( ( p ) => {
            if(p._id === currentUser._id) {
               p.currentUser = currentUser.id
            }
            return p;
         });
    })
 });
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response. It looks like your code returns only user posts. I want to return all posts with user posts marked specifically. In that case I figured I would use some, to see if the post's ID matches some/any of the user.posts' IDs. Basically I would return posts.map

`let markedPosts = posts.map(.....` then `res.json(markedPosts)`

Comment: I think filter without map or some is what you are looking for. All posts in which userPost is marked as true will be in the returned array. If the userPost key is not existent the return p.userPost will be the same as return undefined as the key does not exist so it will not be in the returned array.

Comment: I don't follow this last comment. `user.posts` is an array and `posts` is an array where each post only has a title and ID -- there's no user data here. For each post I need to loop through user.posts to see if the ID matches the post._id. In return I want an array of all the posts, not only user posts. I'm not seeing how filter will give me all posts. It will either give me only user posts or undefined, but I still need the non-user post data. Did I miss something?

Comment: It is hard to understand what it is you are trying to do. Calling the model Post is a bit confusing. So, this is a router.post rather then a router.get that you are doing? So, there will be a new post and you want to find all posts with the same id as the user that is sent in the post request?

Comment: oh sorry, the model `Post` is like an article post - nothing to do with the HTTP method types. So we can forget about how data is being communicated with the server. I'm just looking for a best convention to modify data returned from my database to mark some of the data as having an association with the `currentUser`